# Error installing RVAideMemoire on ubuntu 18 (no mixOmics available)

Tags: repository, install.packages

When I try to install RVAideMemoire I have an error because ine of the packages is not available for R 3.4.4
Is there any other way to install this package

```
install.packages("RVAideMemoire")
```

Comment: RVAideMemoire is in CRAN, but mixOmics is in BioConductor. You need to manually install mixOmics first.

Answer (score 0):

I spent the afternoon to fix "mixOmics".

First, I installed the R version 3.6.0.

Then, for me, the trick was to install the development version with [their instructions](https://github.com/mixOmicsTeam/mixOmics).

Comment: The content in the link can change over time and become irrelevant, so it'd be better if you included how to install the development version in your answer.  You could still include the link for "more info".